# storing date into mongodb using python in ISO format

Tags: python, date, bottle

I am trying to store date into mongodb using python(bottle framework).
I want to store it in the below format:

```
ISODate("2015-06-08 03:38:28")
```

Currently I am using the following command:

```
datetime.strptime(DateField, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

it is getting stored like this:

```
ISODate("2015-06-08T03:38:28Z")
```

How to store it without **`"T"`** and **`"Z"`** in it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing how something is *stored* vs. how something is *displayed*.

In MongoDB, [dates are stored as 64 bit integers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date), what you are seeing is the way it is represented so that we can easily determine what date and time the 64bit number represents.

The `ISODate` is just a helper method, which formats the date in the [ISO date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

So when you pass it in a normal date and time string, it will convert it into the correct format.

The format adds the `T` (to separate the time part) and the `Z` (as you have not identified a time zone, it is defaulted to UTC).

In short - you are not storing it with the T and the Z, that's just how it is displayed back to you.